# How to force android's actionbar (using Actionbar-Sherlock) buttons to be on the right?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using Actionbar-Sherlock in my app.
Every thing works well but when I change the locale of the app to 'iw' the actionbar buttons move to left and the icon moves to the right.
How can I keep the it in the default view (icon-left buttons-right)?

Comment: Can you add some screen shots ?

Comment: I cannot, that was a year ago. I solved it since. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using a custom view for the action bar.